# Confused about lxml and trying to drill down into pages

Tags: python, lxml

I'm trying to scrape some schools data for a project and have got stuck. Here's my code so far. Simple approach with requests and lxml - although it is a while since I've used either.

```
import pandas as pd

import requests
from lxml import etree
from io import StringIO, BytesIO
import random

f = requests.get("https://www.isc.co.uk/schools/england/")
parser = etree.HTMLParser()
tree = etree.parse(StringIO(str(f.content)), parser)
parent_domain = "http://www.isc.co.uk"

links = tree.xpath('//*[@id="maincontent"]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/ul/li/a')

link_urls = [parent_domain+l.get("href") for l in links]

areas_40 = random.sample(link_urls, 40)
areas_40
```

It returns something like this:

```
['http://www.isc.co.uk/schools/england/derbyshire/',
 'http://www.isc.co.uk/schools/england/west-midlands/',
 'http://www.isc.co.uk/schools/england/lancashire/',
 'http://www.isc.co.uk/schools/england/dorset/',
 'http://www.isc.co.uk/schools/england/devon/'...]



#load area pages 
area_pages = [requests.get(h) for h in areas_40[0]]

MissingSchema: Invalid URL 'h': No scheme supplied. Perhaps you meant http://h?
            
area_page_data_links= tree2.xpath('//a')
link_urlss = [parent_domain+l.get("href") for l in area_page_data_links]
```

I've had the code working for single instances but I want to drill down into local areas and then individual schools, but nothing seems to work. I just seem to get the results you see above.

Comment: when you are using `for h in areas_40[0]` it will split url into characters. so your line would be like `[requests.get(h) for h in areas_40]`. And if just one request for 1 URL, then can try `area_pages = [requests.get(h) for h in areas_40[:1]]`

Comment: welcome back to python world :)